# Diagnosing Java interrupt flags

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I have some code that looks like this:

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            doWork();
        }
    }
});
```

This code is sometimes failing to exit the while loop because the interrupt flag is being cleared somewhere inside `doWork()`.  This method makes calls to third party libraries, one of which is swallowing the interrupt.

Firstly, are there any specific techniques I could use to diagnose this?  Secondly, are there any static analysis tools that would be able to spot this sort of bug?

Comment: I guess one thing I could try is setting a breakpoint on `InterruptedException`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there any specific techniques I could use to diagnose this?

You could extend `Thread` and override the `interrupt()` method to set your own internal interrupt flag.  Then you could compare your internal flag with the thread state after 'doWork()` finishes to see if they differ.

You could always interrupt the thread yourself and see if the interrupt flag is cleared when it exits from `doWork();`.  This is obviously going to screw up your logic.

> are there any static analysis tools that would be able to spot this sort of bug?

None that I know of.  One of the profilers might be smart enough to catch thread interrupts.

Comment: I do interrupt the thread myself using `Future.cancel()`.  But sometimes the while loop continues to run.  I've verified that interruption is the problem by making my own interruption mechanism out of a `volatile boolean` field.

Comment: I assume that you use `Future.cancel(true);`.  If the boolean field gets set then you know that the 3rd party library is not setting the interrupt correctly.  You could just use your field instead of the interrupt flag of course @hertzsprung.  Not sure what else there is to be done.

Comment: Yup, I use `Future.cancel(true)`.  I will stay with my boolean field for now but interruption, if I could get it to work reliably, could be used to wake up from blocking I/O that occurs inside `doWork()`.  Seems like Java interrupts are real minefield.  I'll keep investigation, though ;-)

Comment: Actually, interrupts are quite reliable, but if a third-party library does something foolish like catching InterruptedException and throwing it away, well, that renders interrupts useless.  (The proper thing for a library to do, in almost every case, is to declare the method with `throws InterruptedException`.)

Comment: Out of interest, what is the motivation for the interrupt flag being reset when InterruptedException is caught?  Since you are supposed to rethrow it, or set the flag manually, wouldn't it be preferable to leave the flag set?